# to deploy docker on apache2 server

Tags: html, apache, docker

I have my html application that runs in apache2 server and I want to dockerize the html application that should be run in docker container using apache2 package. I tried but got docker build failed. I dont want to use nginx server help me with apache.

Here is the following Dockerfile content in html application

```
FROM apache2:2.4.18
WORKDIR /var/www/html/startapp
COPY . /var/www/docker
```

Then I tried to build this with docker using

```
sudo docker build -t startapp .
```

It returns:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  335.6MB
Step 1/3 : FROM apache2:2.4.18
pull access denied for apache2, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

If its not possible with apache2 so there is change to build by lampp server in ubuntu 16.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the base image (the one that you are using is not available as on default docker registry).

```
FROM httpd:2.4
```

Take a look at https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use a non-official docker image for Apache, So either you build apache2 image using its `Dockerfile` if you have it. Or you can login to the private repository that holds apache2 image if you have its credentials. Otherwise you may use the [official Apache docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/)

Comment: Thanks for the improve formatting and notifying use of non-official docker package Apache